# MVC, Elmah, apparent hacker attempts and "generic" IgnoreRoutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anyone give advice on filtering my Elmah (http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)  exception logs?

Elmah has been a very valuable tool in highlighting my obvious mistakes and oversights in my web application.

However now .. most Elmah entries do not pertain to my own stupidity (well -- perhaps they do -- thus my question), but any advice would be much appreciated.

My Elmah log now has 10'000s of entries similar to:

- The controller for path
  '/ws/login.php' could not be found or
  it does not implement IController.
- The controller for path
  '/text/javascript' could not be found
  or it does not implement IController.
- The controller for path
  '/jlkqyvaugdaktp.html' could not be
  found or it does not implement
  IController.  [[ Actually 100s of
  these!! ... Do these random pages
  mean something in "HackerDom"? ]]
- The controller for path
  '/Scripts/thickbox/macFFBgHack.png'
  could not be found or it does not
  implement IController.

**So .. to the "Question"**

It is obvious that that the  vast majority of these exceptions are being generated by IController ... can I tell Elmah just to "forget" about those and continue to log my *genuine* exceptions?

Or is it that my very generic MVC IgnoreRoute setup is not good enough? Should I ignore "*.htm*", "*.php" and all the others so I can more realistically see Elmah reports about pages/items/objects that my application perhaps more genuinely missing?

Many thanks for your time and consideration.

My Existing Route setup looks like this:

```
         routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*forums}", new { forums = @"cccForums/.*" });
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.txt");

///  REAL ROUTES
            routes.MapRoute(
                "ItemIndex", // Route name
                "Item/Index/{page}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "PageItem", action = "Index", page = 1} // Parameter defaults
                );

.............
.............


/// LAST CASE

 routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}", new { controller = "Site", action = "Map" });
```

Comment: A "Rave from the Grave" update ---  I have noticed that now I am using Chrome as my main debug tool, many more of these errors are appearing since Chrome will try and load a page on each keypress in it's address bar as part of its "real-time" loading:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to implement a catch all route that would redirect all unknown request to a 404 page.  This would prevent an uncaught exception and your end users get a pretty page (the non-hacker variety).

```
routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}",
        new { controller = "Error", action = "http404" }
    );
```

Place this at the end of your register route function in the global.asax.  You should see all of your ELMAH errors disappear.

**EDIT**

Don't go to sleep yet! :)If your interested in not logging 404 errors (or any other type of errors for that matter with ELMAH), you should be able to do something like this in your web.config:

```
<elmah>
    ...
    <errorFilter>
        <test>
            <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
        </test>
    </errorFilter>
</elmah>
```

[ELMAH ErrorFiltering Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/ErrorFiltering)

Comment: Tommy .. this is sounding good ... but I already have something similar ... but I will test .....

I have updated my question with my current Route setup

Comment: Just tested .. with "www.mysite.com/thisPageiskjhkjhkjh.htm"  .. MVC routing DID redirect to  "www.mysite.co.uk/Site/Map" ... but the Elamh exception is still logged :(

Comment: hah .. maybe that is being caught by my Web.config :

  <customErrors mode="Off">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Site/Map"/>
  </customErrors>

Comment: & @Craig ... many thanks to both of you for your help ...Whichever way I try and test, Elmah still seems to be catching an exception ...... I think I will have to d/load the source and debug .... unfortunately too late for me tonight ... but I will make some time over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore these via `IgnoreRoute`, then the crack attempt is still making it as far as ASP.NET. That loads your server. Why not block these at your firewall instead?

Comment: If he is on shared hosting, this would be impossible.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - but would that not mean that essentially I would have to maintain my "real" routes on my firewall, using a completely differnt syntax and build cycle?

Comment: @JcMalta, it depends. Most firewalls let you do excludes, not just includes. @Tommy, it seems to me that you're presuming a hardware firewall, but software firewalls (including the one built into Server 2008 SP 2) would still be preferable to doing this in ASP.NET IMHO.